# should I use mysql enum or tinyint for fields having values 1 and 0?

Tags: mysql

I use tinyint (1) for fields which contain either 1 or 0, for xample, is_active. I can use enum ('1','0') instead but not sure which cases I should use enum or tinyint. Any comments/suggetion?

Thanks

Js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case both `enum` and `tinyint` will have the same size (i.e. `1 byte`). However, the `enum` option is less flexible if your data changes. So use it if you're *absolutely sure* your data definition will not change (eg. what if you will you be adding a `'disabled'` state in the future?).

If you decide to stick with the `enum` a definition like `enum('active', 'not_active')` is more practical.

Answer (score 1):

> BOOL , BOOLEAN. These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1)

I think you should go for `tinyint(1)`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the database engine chooses to do under the hood.  If you're never going to grow beyond two options, I'd recommend tinyint - but I doubt it makes much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference would be to use `TINYINT(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

An `enum('active', 'inactive')` would use the advantages of an enum better than `enum(0, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Enum is good if you want to have specific values - for instance:

```
enum('y','n')
```

But if you just need a simple boolean, use tinyint(1).